# Postman: How to compare variable with value in pre-request script?

Tags: javascript, json, postman

I have a variable value that is either true or false set in a JSON file. For my pre-request script, how would I compare the value of a variable with an expected value? Right now I am doing:

```
if (pm.variables.get("VARIABLE_NAME")=="true"){ ... }
```

However, the if statement is running everytime, regardless of whether VARIABLE_NAME is set as true or false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only idea I have is that if you have bool value in "VARIABLE_NAME", it is always true when you compare using "==" bool to non-empty string ("test" is a string)

Comment: Thanks, that was partially the problem, I also had another local variable that was interfering with the value.